# How to run 64 bit apps on 32 bit os

Tags: linux, 64-bit

I am using 32 bit openSUSE OS, and I am using a cross compiler to build 64 bit application( it does not support building 32 apps) as our software will be deployed on a machine which is 64 bit OS. As testing on target is not always possible, is there anyway to run this applications on my 32 bit OS.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: No, it doesn't... this is cross-compilation.

Comment: @AndrewMcGregor What is cross-compilation?

Comment: Cross compilation is building software on one machine that is destined to run on something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use something like QEMU that can emulate a 64-bit processor.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** No, there is no way.

**Longer answer:** If you have a 64-bit CPU it may be possible to run a 64-bit virtual machine, even though your host OS is 32-bit. I'm not 100% sure about that, though, you'd have to try it.

Comment: Yes, you can run 64-bit VMs on a 32-bit host OS, provided the CPU supports it.

Comment: I believe this is implemented in VirtualBox.